# Print 1 below specific value until meets a higher value

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I have data where I wish to print 1s when below a certain value until we meet a higher value.

Take this data for example:

```
        data long_entry long_exit
1  80.000000          0         1
2   7.692308          1         0
3   7.692308          1         0
4   8.333333          1         0
5   9.090909          1         0
6  20.000000          1         0
7  27.272727          0         0
8  50.000000          0         0
9  50.000000          0         0
10 21.428571          1         0
11 58.333333          0         0
12 46.666667          0         0
13 78.064516          0         1
14 86.153846          0         1
15 42.857143          0         0
16 44.186047          0         0
17 20.000000          1         0
18 25.000000          0         0
19 40.000000          0         0
20 45.000000          0         0
21 78.000000          0         1
22 55.000000          0         0
```

My goal is to print 1,s when data column is below 25 and continue to print 1 until we meet a data number over 70 (first instance).

Code used to make long / exit signals:

```
df$long_entry = ifelse(df$data < 25,1,0 )  
df$long_exit = ifelse(df$data >= 70,1,0)
```

I have tried writing a few for loops using base and dplyr:

```
  df$final.signal[[1]] = ifelse(df$long_entry[[1]] == 1, 1, 0)

  for (i in 2:nrow(df)){
    df$final.signal[i] = ifelse(df$long_entry[i] ==1, 1, 0,
                          ifelse(df$long_exit[i] == 1, 0,
                                 df$long_exit[i-1]))
  }

  df <- df %>%
    dplyr::mutate(final.signal = ifelse(long_entry == 1, 1,
                                    ifelse(long_exit ==1, 0, 0)))
```

This however does not do as intended. The desired output is to be like this:

```
        data desired.output
1  80.000000              0
2   7.692308              1
3   7.692308              1
4   8.333333              1
5   9.090909              1
6  20.000000              1
7  27.272727              1
8  50.000000              1
9  50.000000              1
10 21.428571              1
11 58.333333              1
12 46.666667              1
13 78.064516              1  (1 on first instance over 70)
14 86.153846              0
15 42.857143              0
16 44.186047              0
17 20.000000              1 (back to 1 when under 25)
18 25.000000              1
19 40.000000              1
20 45.000000              1
21 78.000000              1 ( stay 1 until first instance over 70)
22 85.000000              0
```

We see we print 1 < 25 until we meet the first instance of >70.

Which is the best method to approach this task?

Comment: Why is row 13 (and 14) not 0? And after a 0, do you decide when to go back to 1's?

Comment: I want row 13 to be 1 and 14 to be 0. I turn to 0's after meeting the first instance over 70. Then back to 1's when below 25... and stay 1 until first instance of over 70, after 0's - updated, sorry got late last night

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this could help you :

```
dataa <- data.frame(abs(rnorm(mean = 30, sd = 40, n= 100)))
names(dataa) <- c("v1")
dataa %>% mutate(v2 = as.numeric( (cumsum(as.numeric(dataa$v1>70)) <= 0) & (cumsum(as.numeric(dataa$v1<25)) >= 1)))
```

Comment: This is correct! Is there a way to go back to 0 after first instance over 70?

Comment: May be you can play with the cumsum, substracting them for exemple .. I think you can find a way to do it.